# Cross data in list

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
table = [[['NAME', 'CITY', 'YEAR', 'CLASS'], 
          [['Andrew', 'New York', '1982', 'A'], 
           ['Adam', 'Chicago', '1985', 'C'], 
           ['George', 'Phoenix', '1990', 'B']]]]
```

how can I get this output?

```
NAME: Andrew, Adam, George
CITY: New York, Chicago, Phoenix
YEAR: 1982, 1985, 1990
CLASS: A, C, B
```

I have tried different ways but the only thing I have managed to do is to cross the data in the opposite way from what I want (i.e. NAME with the first line, CITY with the second and so on).

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Please update the approaches you tried in the question.

Comment: A lot of lists in there. Could the result of `print(list(zip(*table[0][1])))` help you?

Comment: @Matthias That could help but that way I lose the headers (NAME, CITY, YEAR, CLASS): 
This is the ouput:
[('Andrew', 'Adam', 'George'),
 ('New York', 'Chicago', 'Phoenix'),
 ('1982', '1985', '1990'),
 ('A', 'C', 'B')]

Comment: Of course you will have to take the headers into account. Like a loop with `for header, values in zip(table[0][0], zip(*table[0][1])):` and then as the body of the loop `print(f'{header}: {", ".join(values)}')`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `unpacking` to achieve this:

```
>>> table = [[['NAME', 'CITY', 'YEAR', 'CLASS'], 
             [['Andrew', 'New York', '1982', 'A'], 
              ['Adam', 'Chicago', '1985', 'C'], 
              ['George', 'Phoenix', '1990', 'B']]]]

>>> [[keys, values]] = table
>>> for key, value in zip(keys, zip(*values)):
        print(f"{key}: {', '.join(value)}")

NAME: Andrew, Adam, George
CITY: New York, Chicago, Phoenix
YEAR: 1982, 1985, 1990
CLASS: A, C, B
```

A less readable one-liner (more like a 5-liner):

```
>>> print(*(
            f"{key}: {', '.join(value)}" 
            for [keys, values] in table 
            for key, value in zip(keys, zip(*values))
           ), sep='\n')

NAME: Andrew, Adam, George
CITY: New York, Chicago, Phoenix
YEAR: 1982, 1985, 1990
CLASS: A, C, B
```

Comment: Unpacking this with `[[keys, values]] = table` is a good idea. That makes it more readable than the same approach I presented in the comments.